# How can I list all pads in etherpad-lite

Tags: indexing, etherpad

I found this: https://github.com/ether/etherpad-lite/wiki/How-to-list-all-pads

But I really cannot figure how to use it. Do I have to modify my templates/index.html and add that piece of code? Where? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There are some [plugins](https://github.com/ether/etherpad-lite/wiki/Available-Plugins) for that:

- [small-list](https://npmjs.org/package/ep_small_list)
- [list_pads](https://npmjs.org/package/ep_list_pads)
- [padlist](https://npmjs.org/package/ep_list_pads)

GitHub:

- [padlister](https://github.com/Visono/padlister)
- [pad-lister](https://github.com/ktt-ol/ep_pad-lister)

For me personally, `small-list` was the best choice as I had some problems with the others.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled to make it work too, so I contacted Rob - the guy who coded the script. He says that it might be obsolete for the latest version of etherpad-lite.

Answer (score 0):

Login in etherpad admin, Then go the Plugin Manager and choose/search **"list_pads"** from Available Plugins And Press install button.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUwuH.png)
Or Through Command line 
Command is "npm install ep_list_pads"